# Python print json with \u escape, getting wrong decoding

Tags: python, json, windows, unicode, python-unicode

Python 2.7.13 Windows AMD64

Having trouble handling a JSON file using \u Unicode format.

Test Case

```
import json

testJ = json.load(open("simple.json"))
print(testJ['a'])
```

simple.json

```
{"a": "\u00AA"}
```

output

```
┬¬
```

desired output

```
ª
```

How do I get the desired output using Python? If I use `jq` tool

```
jq ".a" < simple.json
```

I get the expected output

Comment: Sounds like a locale mismatch.  You want to make sure Python is configured to use UTF-8 on standard output.  This is a very common FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the IDE that you are using.

But if you want to print out unicode characters on Window command lines, try this:
`C:\>chcp 65001`
It will support the display of UTF-8 encoded text.